# awstats_updateall.pl now -> Error: Can't scan directory /etc/awstats

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, awstats

In the awstats.model.conf sampel file they say:

> The config file must be in
>   /etc/awstats, /usr/local/etc/awstats
>   or /etc (for Unix/Linux) or same
>   directory than awstats.pl (Windows,
>   Mac, Unix/Linux...)

My awstats.www.mydomain.com.conf is in the same directory as the awstats.pl but when I run awstats_updateall.pl now I get this error message:

Error: Can't scan directory /etc/awstats.

Anyone any idea?

Regards,
Marcel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay my fault. Did not run the awstats_updateall.pl with the right parameters

Comment: Glad you resolved this issue. Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.